# Oracle Apex Chart with Time Series Axis causing formatting errors with bar width

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-jet, oracle-apex-23

Using time series data with multiple series, when the Chart Attribute of Time Axis Type is set to Enabled or Mixed Frequency, it causes formatting issues with the width of the bar spanning more than one day, but also to the day either side of it. You can see in the screenshot below there are 3 bars, one for the 26th, one for the 27th and one for the 29th, all of which overlap by 1 day either side of their respectiv date.

[image]

This only occurs with some data, however, I have not been able to find any meaningfull pattern between the data that causes this error and the data that does not.

I have tried different axis types, different zoom / initial zoom. The only thing I can offer is that with some of my datasets this doesn't occur. These 'different' data sets are prouced by the same SQL query from the same database, with no meaningful difference that I can discern between the data.

[image]

[image]

There have been sources online about changing the width using the oracle JET OJ-Chart library, however, these settings are not exposed inside of Oracle Apex.